# Creating Datestamp cells in UICollectionViewController when the day changes

Tags: ios, swift

Creating a chat app, like iMessage, But not sure of how to include the cells that contain the date, when the day changes. I tried using a header to the collectionViewCell , but it didn't seem to work. Here is the code where I add the header.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

    let reusableview = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "HCollectionReusableView", for: indexPath) as! HCollectionReusableView
    reusableview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    if(indexPath.item > 1){
    let timestamp1 = (messages[indexPath.item ].timestamp?.doubleValue)!
    let timestamp2 = (messages[indexPath.item - 1].timestamp?.doubleValue)!
    if NSCalendar.current.isDate(Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timestamp1), inSameDayAs: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timestamp2)) == false {
        reusableview.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true
        switch kind {
        case UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader:
            let calendar = NSCalendar.current
            let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: (messages[indexPath.item ].timestamp?.doubleValue)!)
            if calendar.isDateInYesterday(date) {
                reusableview.DateStamp.text = "Yesterday"
            }
            else if calendar.isDateInToday(date) {
                reusableview.DateStamp.text = "Today"
            }
            else{
                if let seconds = messages[indexPath.item].timestamp?.doubleValue {
                    let timestampDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: seconds)

                    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
                    reusableview.DateStamp.text = dateFormatter.string(from: timestampDate)
                }
                print(reusableview.DateStamp.text!)
                }
                default:  fatalError("Unexpected element kind")
            }
            return reusableview
        }}
    reusableview.DateStamp.text = ""
    reusableview.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0).isActive = true
    return reusableview
}
```

But the header doesn't appear.
[Screenshot Attached. The date should appear in the middle like imessage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0FLz.png)

Any solutions?

Comment: Do you set the custom class and the Identifier in the storyboard correctly?
Do you try debugging if it is called? 
Do you implemented the numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) ... ?
When the header is at least not shown the given code is not very helpful ;)

Comment: @John Custom class and identifier is correctly set in storyboard. Just verifying, what should be the numberOfSections value? Currently it returns 2.
I tried adding a breakpoint at timestamp1 statement, but turns out it never gets to that part of the code.

Comment: I try to be short: We start a conversation today so we have one section with rows in section count equal to a number of our messages. Now imagine tomorrow you write me again: The situation will be we have two sections with an amount of rows equal to the messages related to the day. I like to use a two-dimensional array for this. Check out a simple example with static content :-)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use an two-dimensional array and make yourself clear where to save the date and where the messages. A good starting point could be:

```
var items: [[CustomType?]] = []

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("section \(section)")
        print("items count \(items[section].count)")
        return items[section].count
}

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return items.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind,
                                                                     withReuseIdentifier: "sectionHeader",
                                                                     for: indexPath) as! HeaderCollectionReusableView
    if items[indexPath.section].count >= 1 {
        if let sectionId = items[indexPath.section][0] {
            let date: String = sectionId.id
            headerView.dateLabel.text = date
            return headerView
        }
    }
    headerView.dateLabel.text = "fix it"
    return headerView
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "imageCell", for: indexPath) as! ImageCollectionViewCell
    guard let currentImage = items[indexPath.section][indexPath.item] else {
        //configure
        return cell
    }
    cell.configure(withPicture: currentImage)
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Hey, John. I get the idea! I'll try it out and let you know! :)